# MR scanner versus MRI scanner

Tags: terminology, medical-imaging, mri

To designate a device that performs magnetic resonance imaging (MRI), is the proper term MR scanner or MR**I** scanner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no consistency within the industry on the terminology. For example, GE calls them [MR systems](http://www3.gehealthcare.com/en/Products/Categories/Magnetic_Resonance_Imaging), Philips calls them both [MR system and MRI system](http://www.usa.philips.com/healthcare/product/HC781341/ingenia-15t-mr-system), Toshiba calls them both [MRI system](https://medical.toshiba.com/products/magnetic-resonance/vantage-titan-3t/) and [MR system](https://medical.toshiba.com/download/mr-br-vantage-titan-3t), and Siemens calls them [MRI scanners](http://usa.healthcare.siemens.com/magnetic-resonance-imaging).